# Kill Application

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to kill my app after 10 second, I want to start service that kill app after getting Kill Action. But this code noting after 10 second. Why?

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, service_MyService.class);
intent.setAction("Kill");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,intent, 0);
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Try to see [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are sending a broadcast intent

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,intent, 0);
```

Which can only start a BroadCastReceiver and not a service. However, you are using the right intent, because AlarmManager can not wake up a services, only BroadCastReceiver-s.

You should create a BroadCastReceiver instead of a service, and replace this line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, service_MyService.class);
```

with this line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, KillerBroadCastReceiver.class);
```

and then in your KillerBroadCastReceiver class you kill the app.

However if you want to kill the app after some time, a better solution is to use a Handler. Here is an example:

```
public class VeryFirstActivity extends Activity {
    Handler mKillerHandler;

    public void onCreate(...) {
        mKillerHandler = new Handler();
        mKillerHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               VeryFirstActivity.this.finish();
           }
        }, 10000); // 10 seconds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not good because Android want to manage application by it self but you can do it like this.

```
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may kill your activity by using:

```
finish();
```

Or you can kill your app:

```
System.exit(0);
```

But both are not suggested. Android system is not suitable for this. Android OS controls to kill apps.

More information is [here](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html)

Comment: You are saying that finish() is not suggested?