# Trying to learn how to use intent and broadcast to kill my application. Why is it not dying?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, alarmmanager

I am almost finished with this game I have been making. It is a toy app and is only serving to teach me. So I call it toyapp.

I am trying to use what I learned about alarmmanager, intent, and broadcast to kill my application. I figured out how to get my alarm to go 10 seconds and then print a message to a widget. This was based on the following tutorial [here](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129).

It was my thinking that I could just call this up, warn the user I am about to kill this application and then close it out. However, it appears that the AlarmReceiver is not being called at all? My game just keeps playing.

The code I have modified is below for my toyapp.

```
public void timingService(Context context, Activity activity){
    // get a Calendar object with current time
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

 // add 5 minutes to the calendar object
 cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

 Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class);
 intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "Game will exit soon");


 // In reality, you would want to have a static variable for the request code instead of 192837
 PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 // Get the AlarmManager service
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) activity.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

}
```

Now, put my Receiver code in my activity class. Which is as follows:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try{
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Give message
                toyappActivity.this.finish(); //Exit the game

            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }//End of AlarmReciever
```

My inspiration for this approach was the following that I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750034/kill-application).

What I eventually want to do is simple. I will have an option to play the game with or without the alarm. I plan on reseting the alarmmanager with the accelerometer sensor if movement is detected. Otherwise, it will just countdown and then cancel the game.

I suspect I am not understanding intents directly, but this is my crashing point. I am so sorry if this seems stupid, but I have a rather bad cold right now and this seems like it should work to me. However, computers never lie, only our minds.

As always, you are all the best group of coders and developers. I learn so much from you all and your help is so much appreciated. Any dumb mistakes are my own, but I hope you let me off on that technicality.

Warm Regards, 
GeekyOmega

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alarm is set properly: `am.set(...)`, it should be called only once.
But you would expect a message on you screen with:

```
Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Give message
```

The proces will refer to a `:remote` not sure the context what will be, as I remmeber the appContext. It seems you are trying to show a message from background and your GUI may block it. Try to remove (comment) that maeesage and let the

```
toyappActivity.this.finish(); //Exit the game
```

code run, just do a `Log.d()` if you want.

Comment: Commenting out the Toast made no difference. :-/ What is weird is that if I have AlarmReciever as it's own java class, it works. I then move it to Activity, then it doesn't work?

Comment: In my app I have a whole package which has only the Broadcast receivers: each receiver is a different class. But that is my "coding style". In your code I saw you have a dedicated class too: `public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Agreed. I mimc you "style". However, any ideas how I could kill the game in a separate receiver that doesn't exist in activity. In other words, how can I kill the app in the receiver which is a separate class?

Comment: Hint: with JNI everything is possible. I am to lazzy to write a solution here, probably somebody will give you a ready for copy-paste code which you will upvote and accept it

Comment: No need to be sarcastic. You know what I did? I am doing two things: 1. Implementing a service class which will limit total game play in minutes and send notification to user. (Just to teach notifications).

Comment: 2. When you can't get what you find to work, you code something you need yourself. So I put a timer in view and reset it everytime the accelerometer is updated. Which unfortunately is always. Once I figure out how to "detect" mostly no movement. It will exit the entire game.

Comment: Anyway, I consider you as having answered this question since it lead me to try 1 and 2. I may have to get some help on notifications since it updates only once and that's it. O_O. I would normally figure this stuff out, but I have the flu, not a cold. :-(

Comment: I am working on a project, where I need a tick() in a defined time elapsed. Only the Alarm is good enough for me, The Service in Android 2.3 has bug, even with flag Sticky. Not sure why, when, what reason, but the service can go in background ( altought I "told:" to be in foreground" and we will do those ticks in a buffer, and when the user becomes again active, than will release those buffers, ( even with 100 tick...) my advice is to stay with Alarm, try to search how to unregister from alarm service, if your business model needed. Hopefully in Android 4 they has fixed that bug, but idk!

Answer (score 1):

The [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class isn't designed for simple timeouts.

From the documentation in the link above...

> **Note:** The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. **For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.**

See the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class to do what you want more efficiently.

Comment: I can't use Handler because I am going to use the accelerometer in my view class to time out my program from idling. I could use the Handler however if I wanted to put a limit to how long I am going to allow the user to play the game?